# RhinoMock test mock interface void functions?

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm new to RhinoMock's just been doing state unit testing up till now.

How do you test void functions?

Getting the following complie error when setting up expectation,

*Expression does not produce a value*

Basically I want to test that a certain mock's method is called a certain amount of times.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use LastCall.

http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/api/files/LastCall-cs.html

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you can use the Expect.Call method with a lambda:

```
Expect.Call(() => someVoidFunction());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this project is pre 3.5.
I will try this out in other projects though 
cheers